# MySQL AVG then Sort By Result

Tags: mysql

I have a rather large MYSQL database where I need to average all of the invoices and then query the highest value of those averages. My query will join three tables to get the proper data for display. The tables are brand, product, and line. The columns I need are brand_name and brand_id from brand, line_price from line, and product joins the brand and inventory tables.

```
SELECT brand.brand_id, brand.brand_name, brand.brand_type, ROUND(MAX(line_price),2) AS 'Highest AVG Price'
FROM (SELECT brand.brand_id, brand_name, brand_type, AVG(line_price) AS line_price FROM product, brand, line
WHERE product.prod_sku = line.prod_sku
AND product.brand_id = brand.brand_id
GROUP BY brand_id)w1, brand
WHERE w1.brand_id = brand.brand_id;
```

When I run the query I get the correct value but the wrong brand_name and brand_id. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please give your current `SELECT`?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a JOIN:

```
SELECT b.brand_id, b.brand_name, b.brand_type, 
ROUND(MAX(line_price),2) AS 'Highest AVG Price' 
FROM product p JOIN brand b ON p.brand_id = b.brand_id 
JOIN line l ON l.prod_sku = p.prod_sku GROUP BY b.brand_id
```

Please let me know if the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get what you mean by max average price. Do you need average price for each brand or for each product? Or you need the brand with maximum average product price?